# My C function is working but I'm not sure why

Tags: c, loops

I have written a C function that prints a square composed of `*` and `+`, like this:

```
 * + + + +
 * * + + +
 * * * + +
 * * * * +
 * * * * *
```

The function works perfectly, though, I'm not sure why it's working having `MAX_LENGHT - 1`.

Here's my code:

```
void quadratoScalaPiu(int MAX_LENGHT) {
    
    printf("\nCaso 4\n\n");

    // Colonna
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGHT; i++) {   
            
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
            printf("* ");
        }
       
        for (int j = i; j < MAX_LENGHT - 1; j++) {
            printf("+ ");
        }

        printf("\n");

    }
}
```

I would be really grateful if anyone could take a look to my function and tell me the reason of this mystery.

Having the second for loop: `(int j = i; j < MAX_LENGHT; j++)` (Not `MAX_LENGHT - 1`), the loop iterates one extra time, which isn't needed.

I would have this output:

```
* + + + + +
* * + + + +
* * * + + +
* * * * + + 
* * * * * +
```

Comment: Aside: [length](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/length) (sp.) - a common typo.

Comment: Change `printf("* ");` to `printf( "* i%d j%d", i, j );` to add _print debugging_ to your code. Do the same with the print of the `'+'`. Study the numbers and work it out for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first loop iterates until `j == i`. Then your second loop starts with `j = i` again, so there are two iterations for the same value of `j`. If the limit of the second iteration were `j < MAX_LENGHT` you would get an extra column because of that duplication.

Instead of subtracting from `MAX_LENGHT`, you could simply start the second loop at the next value of `j`, rather than `i`.

```
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
            printf("* ");
        }
       
        for(; j < MAX_LENGHT; j++) {
            printf("+ ");
        }
```

BTW, you misspelled "length".